# How to tell if N circle intersect each other and in which point?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, artificial-intelligence, robotics

Here's the problem I'm facing: I have a plan, full of obstacles. And I have a silly lost robot. The robot doesn't know where he is! But he knows that he can see some vertices of the obstacles... and using it's sensors, he can tell the distance between himself and each of the visible vertices. Each vertice is a part of an obstacle. The robot doesn't know his position, so he assume that his position is (0, 0). The robot whats to know his position on the map. I'm trying to solve this by multilateration.

The problem is: how to find an intersection point between the N circles and tell the exactly point where it occurs?

In any case that I haven't made my self clear, just ask and I can provide more informations.

EDIT: (Given the pertinent asked questions, I'll try to be more clear)

- I do want to know if all the circles have one (and only one) point of intersection, and I want to know what point is it.
- The vertices location are given to the robot considering that he is the (0, 0), given the fact that he has no idea where he is! So, he only can tell the distance and angle to each vertice (in fact, he receices the coordinates).
- N is bigger than 3

Comment: So... [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)?

Comment: Are the location of the vertices known to the robot?

Comment: Yes, they are! But... they are relative to the robot. The robot doesn't know the coordinates for an X vertices related to the (0, 0) on the map. Only to himself.

Comment: So you want to know if all the circles have a single common point of intersection? Or do you want to know where each pair of circles intersect? The question is not clear on that point. Al the same, you can start with what you know. If two circles are equal, then they intersect at all points; if they are not equal, **technically** they can possibly intersect at one point or two points. Sure I am talking infinitasimal; but that is where you should start. But clarify for me before I can say more.

Comment: I edited @Kolson Labapen... ;)

Comment: @Kevin, I don't have only 3 points... but is like doing a "trilateration" for more than 3 points...

Comment: I'm confused. So you have N vertices V0, V1... VN; and each one is R0, R1, ... RN distance away from the robot at (0,0); and you draw circles with center and radius (V0, R0), (V1, R1),... (VN, RN); and you want to find the intersection of all those circles? They intersect at (0,0), of course. That's practically tautological.

Comment: I know that they intersect at (0, 0). But, the robot's location on the map, related to the (0, 0) of the map, is basically what I want. So, given the circles equations, I will have to try combinations of all vertices on the map in order to find one (and only one) intersection point (didn't really though this through, tough), so I can tell the robot's position on the map!

Comment: It's assumed that there will be only one unique "point of view" for the robot.

Comment: Either you're not giving the robot enough information to solve the problem, or you're not giving us enough information about the problem. Because as it stands, all the robot is getting is information relative to its current position (call it the local coordinate system), and no way to convert from local coordinates to global coordinates. Does the robot know *which* vertex is at distance X and angle Y? With the information you've given, the only solution is to do an exhaustive search on all vertices, and the resulting solution might not be unique.

Comment: @JimMischel Sadly the only solution I found, given what the question tells me, it's this one you mentioned. =/

Answer (score 1):

So, just to re-iterate, your bot has the "map" of all vertices as they pertain to global position VG = {V1g, ..., VNg}. It has a local view of all the vertices VL = {V1l, ..., VNl}, given by angle and distance to it's position - it does not however know which vertex is which globally. It wants to know it's global position. Also given is a "unique" distribution of vertices globally.

If so:

Knowing at least one mapping of vertex from VG -> VL makes problem trivial. Hence, the bot needs to do that first (again assuming unique lay out). Not sure of any point shape/pattern matching algorithms but i am guessing there are a few. You could probably use some tricks like if the convex hull is unique, that makes the problem rather trivial. It is also possible to approach this from graph theory perspective, like say building Minimal Spanning Tree of original global map and then matching it per vertex against local set.